# TypeError: Cannot read property 'lightBoxHandler' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-player

I am trying to auto close the lightbox, once the video is finished playing.

`onEnded` attribute worked great 99.99% of time, but sometimes it's not firing callback. So I tried to use `onDuration`.

Above error occurs in the callback set to `onDuration`. Console prints duration fine but I am not sure why it can't identify following method and throwing error. `this.props.lightBoxHandler(this.props.entry.type);`

```
  renderEntry() {
        if (this.props.entry.type === "photo") {
            this.disableLightbox();
         return  <img alt={Math.random()} src={this.props.entry.entry} onClick={ () => this.props.lightBoxHandler(this.props.entry.type)} />
        } 
        if (this.props.entry.type === "video") {
        return   <ReactPlayer
            url={this.props.entry.entry}
            className='react-player'
            playing={true}
            width='100%'
            height='100%'
            onEnded={() => this.props.lightBoxHandler(this.props.entry.type)}
            onDuration={(duration) => {
                console.log("Duration " + duration);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    this.props.lightBoxHandler(this.props.entry.type);
            }, duration*1000)  }}
            />
        }
    }

    render() {
        let classList = this.props.entry.is === true ? "lightbox-wrapper active" : "lightbox-wrapper";
        return ( 
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className={classList}>
                    {this.renderEntry()}
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
         );
    }
```

Comment: Where is that prop coming from?

Comment: Hi @Max prop is coming from different component. Thing is if I call the same prop for `onEnded`, it works, but when I call it with `onDuration`, it throws error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Change the function inside your `setTimeout` to an arrow function and it should work.

The reason `this.props.lightBoxHandler` is defined in `onEnded` but not in `onDuration` is because in `onDuration` you are calling `this.props` inside of a function in your `setTimeout` that is declared with the `function` keyword, as opposed to an arrow function.

Arrow functions use `this` from the lexical scope. Functions defined with `function` have their own `this`.

See: https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4